# Serial Port Not opening

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to connect to a Serial Port in Visual Studio Window Form App. I have never faced this error below is the piece of code written just for sake of opening the port but error is poping out:

> Error CS0201  Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

What am I missing in this?

```
  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace COM
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            button1.Enabled = true;
         }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            serialPort1.PortName = "COM7";
            serialPort1.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32("9600");
            serialPort1.Parity = Parity.None;
            serialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.Two;
            serialPort1.Open;
            button1.Enabled = false;
        }
        catch(UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot Be OPened");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Should be : serialPort1.Open();

Comment: please consult the documentation to the [Error CS0201](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0201). It tells you : "An invalid statement is any line or series of lines ending in a semicolon that does not represent an assignment (=), **method call ()** , new, -- or ++ " the compiler tells you exactly which line it is that is faulty.

Answer (score 1):

SerialPort.Open is a method, you can call the methode using parentheses:

```
 serialPort1.Open();
```

Answer (score -1):

well it was  a mistake which was done by carelessness, serilport.Open() method must be called with brackets